# How to connect Azure Blob storage through sasTokenUri?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I have a requirement to list down all recently created files names on Azure Blob Storage.
As my team is not owner of Azure account but we are provided **Client Id** and **Client Secret** to connect.
Through *Client Id* and *Client Secret* i am able to generate **sasTokenUri**, i have following questions and any input will be helpful

Question 1: How to connect Azure Blob Storage through **sasTokenUri** and list down all files which are recently created?
Question 2: How can i identify newly created file over Azure Blob storage through the connection stablished above?

**Limitation** : I cannot access Blob storage programmatically through (Python, Java and others) because of some infra limitations, i  only need to access files list through **sasTokenUri** or RestAPI.

**Sample sasTokenUri** :  "https://{Account}.blob.core.windows.net/blob.name?sv=2020-02-10&spr=https&se=2021-07-04T11%3A22%3A05Z&sr=c&sp=rwdl&sig=kL9a1aaaaaaaaaa%2Bbbbbbbb4%2Bccccccc5%2B4vddddddddd0%3D"

Any input or pointers will be helpful.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include how your `sasTokenUri` looks like. Please obfuscate the account name and the `sig` portion of your SAS URI.

Comment: Just added required info.

Comment: Thanks. Added an answer. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your SAS token URI, it seems you're getting a SAS token for a blob container.

To list the blobs in that blob container, simply append `&restype=container&comp=list` to your SAS URI and use that in Postman. So your SAS Token URI will be something like:

```
https://{Account}.blob.core.windows.net/blob.name?sv=2020-02-10&spr=https&se=2021-07-04T11%3A22%3A05Z&sr=c&sp=rwdl&sig=kL9a1aaaaaaaaaa%2Bbbbbbbb4%2Bccccccc5%2B4vddddddddd0%3D&restype=container&comp=list
```

That will give you the list of blobs in that blob container (upto a maximum of 5000 blobs) in XML format. To see more options, please see `List Blobs` REST API operation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs.

Regarding your question about identifying the newly created blobs, Azure Storage does not provide anything out of the box. However each blob as a `Created Date/Time` property that will tell you when a blob was created. You can use this information to find out the newly created blobs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Quick question can we request for a JSON response instead of XML response  and apply some filter logic on identifying new files ? Please suggest

Comment: You can’t. Azure Blob Storage REST API only returns data in XML format.

Comment: ok, any option through which we can extract only newly created files, not all files present on containers.

Comment: No. You’ll need to list all blobs and do the filtering on the client side.

Comment: Do you see any option to resolve it through Marker, MaxResults ?

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways but have you looked at the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)

Can connect via a SaS token through the Connect Dialog and then navigate through the blob storage account similar to File Explorer.

Comment: I am look forward to access through Postman, do you any possible way how we can access through (API) on Postman. Link you have shared is general URL.

Comment: The link is to download a tool w/ a UI.  To use postman I believe it is putting the SaS token in as an authorization type of "Bearer Token" within Postman.

Comment: I have just added sample sas Token which i am able to generate. So you are suggesting that i should try accessing sasToken on Postman ?